# SwiftUI UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without in view hierarchy

Tags: list, warnings, swiftui, view-hierarchy

I have a list in a view (lets call it view A) where I push a view B via NavigationLink from view A and manipulate the CurrentSubjectValue to the initial view A. The moment the data is added and the didChangd.send(value) is dispatched to view A I get a warning that updating a cell that does not belong to a view. It seems that view A is removed from window which is unintuitive based on my previous UINavigationController behavior. Any idea?

View A (MainView)

```
struct MainView: View {

    @ObjectBinding var currentProfileIdStore = CurrentProfileIdStore.shared

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            if (currentProfileIdStore.didChange.value == nil) {
                NavigationLink(destination: ProfilesView()){ Text("show profiles view")}
            } else {
                List {
                    Section {
                        ForEach(0..<1) { _ in
                            PresentationLink(destination: ProfilesView()) {
                                Text("Profiles")
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Section {
                        ForEach(0..<1) { _ in
                            Text("Items")
                        }
                    }
                }.listStyle(.grouped)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(currentProfileIdStore.didChange.value ?? "unknown")

    }
}
```

Then profiles view is presented

```
struct ProfilesView : View {

    @ObjectBinding var profileManager = CurrentProfileIdStore.shared
    @ObjectBinding var profileProvider = ProfileProvider.shared

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(0..<1) { _ in
                        NavigationLink(destination: NewProfile()) {
                            Text("Add Profile")
                        }
                    }
                }


                Section {
                    ForEach(self.profileProvider.didChange.value) { profile in
                        VStack {

                            if profile.id == self.profileManager.didChange.value {
                                Image(systemName: "g.circle").transition(.move(edge: .top))
                            }

                            ProfileCellView(profile: profile)
                            Text(self.profileManager.didChange.value ?? "unknown").font(.footnote).color(.secondary)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Profiles")
                .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }
}
```

and then we could add a new profile

```c
struct NewProfile: View {

    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var successfullyAdded: Bool = false

    @ObjectBinding var keyboardStatus = KeyboardStatus()
    var profileProvider = ProfileProvider.shared

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    if self.successfullyAdded  {
                        Text("Successfully added please go back manually :)").lineLimit(nil)
                    }
                    Form {
                        Section(header: Text("Enter name")) {
                            TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
                        }
                    }
                    if name.count > 3 {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.profileProvider.addProfile(new: Profile(name: self.name, id: UUID().uuidString)) {
                                assert(Thread.isMainThread)
                                self.successfullyAdded = true
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Add")
                        }.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    }
                }.padding(.bottom, self.keyboardStatus.didChange.value)
        }.navigationBarTitle("Add Profile")

    }
}
```

and then there is provider

```c
class ProfileProvider: BindableObject {

    enum Query {
        case all

        var filter: (Profile) -> Bool {
            switch self {
            case .all:
                return { p in true }
            }
        }
    }

    static var samples: [Profile] = []

    static var shared: ProfileProvider = {

        return ProfileProvider(query: .all)
    }()

    var didChange = CurrentValueSubject<[Profile], Never>([])

    private var query: Query?

    private init(query: Query? = nil) {

        self.query = query
        assert(Thread.isMainThread)

        dispatchDidChange()
    }

    func dispatchDidChange() {
        assert(Thread.isMainThread)
        if let valid = self.query {
            didChange.send(ProfileProvider.samples.filter {  valid.filter($0) })
        } else {
            didChange.send([])
        }
    }

    func addProfile(new: Profile, comp: () -> Void) {

        ProfileProvider.samples.append(new)
        comp()
        dispatchDidChange()
    }
```

keep in mind that multiple views share the same provider subject. so the issue happens when the new profile is added.

```
self.profileProvider.addProfile(new
```

there are two more issues, one that when back in mainView the button no longer works.
Also when modally presented I don't yet know how to go back manually.

Comment: #1. It's a warning, right? The important question is - does it work as you expect it to? Remember, `SwiftUI` is barely in beta 3 of version 1! I get those warnings too. Hopefully, this will be improved in future betas. (1) To turn off these warnings, set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable` in your builds. Not necessarily recommending that - but it does get rid of noise. (2) If the behavior is *not* what you'd expect, post some code. So we can help.

Comment: #2. Could it be a timing issue? If so, look at a question I had answer Friday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008251/index-out-of-range-when-binding-a-slider-value-to-a-nested-array-in-environmento

Comment: Consider adding some code. A minimal example that shows us the error. in action Otherwise, it's all speculation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm also seeing this. Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: Something odd about your code which may cause issues: You put your `NavigationLink` for adding a new profile in a `ForEach` for no reason at all. Whats more, the object you give the `ForEach` is not `Identifiable`. Which means that when your data changes the old NavigationLink shouldn't exist. Remove the `ForEach` it does nothing since it goes through `0..1` (one index). I don't know if this solves your problem but its useless code.. so remove it.