# How to return different views based on a certain tag value?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to return a view within a `.sheet` modifier, from an array of view objects. I am having trouble getting the SwiftUI logic for setting tags for different views. This is probably something very simple but I am unable the figure it out.

I have already tried an if statement, and a function with switch/case, but I am unable to return a specific view. I believe since I've added a `tag` manually to the object, once the condition is met, it returns only a single view (`Destination View1`) in all the buttons.

This is my `ForEach` loop for an array of `covers`:

```
var covers = coverData

ForEach(covers) { item in
    Button(action: { self.isPresented.toggle() }) {
        CoverAttributes(title: item.title,
                alternativeTitle: alternativeTitle,
                tapForMore: item.tapForMore,
                color: item.color,
                shadowColor: item.shadowColor)
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresented, content: { Text("Destination View1") })

    }
}
```

The array is structured like this:

```
let coverData = [
    Cover(title: "Title1",
              alternativeTitle: "Alternative title",
              tapForMore: "Tap to see",
              color: Color("background3"),
              shadowColor: Color("backgroundShadow3"),
              tag: 1)

// Three more items with tags 2, 3, 4)

]
```

I want to be able to return the remaining `Destination View2, 3, and 4` for the other buttons as well.

Comment: Exactly how are you setting `tag` in `Cover`? There is no native tag property in `View`. In a more general way, it feels to me like you are trying to "pull" from a `View`, where SwiftUI is designed to "push" from your model to a View. (It also seems to me that you are putting more logic into your views than you should be. In SwiftUI, views are meant to "react" to application state, and not much more.)

Comment: With just a property named "tag". :) I know it's a flawed logic, but I had no idea about how I could distinguish Destination View1 from Destination View2. In either case I'm getting Destination View1 on all 4 buttons.

Comment: What kind of "statefulness" are you using? `BindableObject`? Let's say you code a model where you have 4 views defined (it doesn't matter how, just that it's working). Now, if your buttons update this model - setting something that triggers your target view to update - everything should work. EDIT: Give me a quick minute or two, I may have something to help.

Comment: Okay. About 2 weeks ago I had an issue that, while sounding very different than your's, may help show what I'm talking about. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008251/index-out-of-range-when-binding-a-slider-value-to-a-nested-array-in-environmento ) I needed to *tie* together two lists - where selecting a row or a `Button` meant updating a second list of sliders. The idea is to code what you can in the model, and just let the views "react" to changes in the app state. I just updated the repo - and please ignore the name, it really isn't a list bug! https://github.com/justdfd/ListBug

Comment: I understand what you mean, but this is not valid in my case. What I do need is like a SwiftUI equivalent of ```if sender.tag ==``` that will return a specific view. Thanks though. BTW, why it stops adding steps after 5? That's the bug you're talking about?

Comment: No,the "bug" was that  I was trying to work through "connecting" two lists in my model. Though keeping in mind that we're **extremely** beta right now I'll check that out in my actual app. Thanks! As for your issue? I do think it's the same thing - tags simply don't exist (and maybe shouldn't) in SwiftUI. The concept is to "push" or "drive" things in a "reactive" way from your model **to** your UI. (Sorry for all the emphasis.) Your UI should simply react to changes to your app's state. Bind to it, let *that* change the state, and then have the UI react to it.

Comment: I see, yeah sometimes I think I should just prioritise UIKit learning instead of SwiftUI. Regarding the tags, it was a simple State variable that needed to be assigned, please see answer below. I'm new to programming in general, and the SwiftUI syntax really needs some practice and understanding. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: One piece of advice because you say you are new to programming - learn `UIKit` first. While `SwiftUI` is "where the puck is headed", the OS prerequisites mean most existing apps probably won't use SwiftUI for another OS release **after** the ones this fall. Also, `UIKit` won't be deprecated for - IMHO - another decade or two.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn both. I am doing this one in SwiftUI, since it was meant to be a personal project, but I'm aware that any job chance in this industry goes through UIKit.

Comment: I mean this with respect - good luck! You've chosen a... challenging path. :-) I've been in this profession since mainframe days through Microsoft (COM >> .NET) and for the last 3 years? Semi-retired and `UIKit` apps. This summer is... fun. But I have 3-5 years of Swift and UIKit to help me. Again, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to take the `.sheet` declaration our of the loop, otherwise you'll end up with a lot of `.sheet` "objects" all triggered by the same `$isPresented` and most probably the first one only will be rendered.

So, I think, this will work:

```swift
var covers = coverData
var selectedTag = 0

Group {
   ForEach(covers) { item in
      Button(action: { 
         self.selectedTag = item.tag
         self.isPresented.toggle() 
      }) {
        CoverAttributes(
           title: item.title,
           alternativeTitle: alternativeTitle,
           tapForMore: item.tapForMore,
           color: item.color,
           shadowColor: item.shadowColor)
      }
   }
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresented, content: { 
    Text("Destination View \(self.selectedTag)") 
    // Here you could use a switch statement on selectedTag if you want
})
```

Here's a working playground showing a working example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct Cover {
    var tag: Int
    var title: String
}

struct ContentView : View {

    @State var isPresented = false
    @State var selectedTag = 0

    var covers = [
        Cover(tag: 1, title: "Cover 1"),
        Cover(tag: 2, title: "Cover 2"),
        Cover(tag: 3, title: "Cover 3")
    ]


    var body: some View {
        Group {
            ForEach(covers, id: \.tag) { item in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedTag = item.tag
                    self.isPresented.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(item.title)
                }
           }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresented, content: {
            if self.selectedTag == 1 {
                Text("Tag 1")
            } else if self.selectedTag == 2 {
                Text("Tag 2")
            } else {
                Text("Other tag")
            }
        })
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. The problem with the switch/if statements is, since the tag I give is just another property, once it finds it, it stops checking the other options, and assigns that view to the remaining buttons as well.

What would be ideal is, something that will check the whole thing, and will assign the tags to the buttons. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: It works beautifully, see my updated answer. I added a fully functional playground.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much! It's so simple yet I couldn't see it.