# ScrollView breaks .sheet representation

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to get a sheet representation work nested in multiple views inside a `ScrollView`.

Without the `ScrollView` the `.sheet` modifier works fine, but when I wrap everything inside the scroll view the modifier, triggers only once. So on the first tap the sheet appears fine, but after dismissing it I can not trigger it again. I am unsure whether this is a bug in `SwiftUI` itself or if I am doing something here.

*Note*: If I add the `.sheet` modifier to the `ScrollView` itself, everything is working. But for my use case the `.sheet` modifier is added deeply nested inside a custom view inside the `ScrollView`.

I am using the Xcode Beta 5

**Without ScrollView - Works**

```
struct SheetWorks: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var strings = [
      "Hello", "World", "!"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(strings) { string in
                Button(action: {self.showSheet.toggle()}) {
                    Text(string)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
                    Text("Here is the sheet")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**With ScrollView - Does not work**

```
struct SheetDoesntWork: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var strings = [
      "Hello", "World", "!"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(strings) { string in
                    Button(action: {self.showSheet.toggle()}) {
                        Text(string)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
                        Text("Here is the sheet")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone has experienced something similar or can point me in the right direction. I really appreciate any help.

**Edit: This problem still persists in Beta 6**

Comment: What you are seeing may be a bug. But I just want to point out an error in your code. Since you are putting the `.sheet()` inside the ForEach, you have 3 `.sheet()`. Nothing wrong with that, except they all share the same showSheet variable. So when you toggle it to true, you are presenting three sheets at the same time...

Comment: A `.sheet()` can be attached to anything. I moved my sheets out of the scrollable and attached them to a hidden `Text()`. Well a hidden `Text()` each actually, you can't have a sheet after a sheet.

Comment: I think it's a bug. Even if you move the Button outside the ForEach and you manually create three buttons the issue is still there. Even if you use an array of bools as State instead of just one bool for all the buttons the problem is still there.

Comment: @kontiki you are right, I should not attach the sheet inside the ForEach.

Comment: I also assume that this is a bug, since the sheet works the first time and then is broken. Hope that this will get fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `Xcode 11.1 GM Seed` I can approve that the `.sheet` modifier now works correctly inside the `ScrollView`. Furthermore also a multiline `Text` is now correctly rendered.

Comment: It seems like I have this bug now - XCode 12. ScrollView { ForEach(items) { View() }}} In the view I have a view that has a sheet associated with it. If I change ScrollView to List the sheet renders, otherwise it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57259687/554203

Basically you should use just one `.sheet` outside the loop and dynamically open the  desired view based on a local var.

```swift
var covers = coverData
var selectedTag = 0

Group {
   ForEach(covers) { item in
      Button(action: { 
         self.selectedTag = item.tag
         self.isPresented.toggle() 
      }) {
        CoverAttributes(
           title: item.title,
           alternativeTitle: alternativeTitle,
           tapForMore: item.tapForMore,
           color: item.color,
           shadowColor: item.shadowColor)
      }
   }
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresented, content: { 
    Text("Destination View \(self.selectedTag)") 
    // Here you could use a switch statement on selectedTag if you want
})
```

Comment: You are 100% correct that I should apply my `sheet` modifier outside of the `ForEach`. But unfortunately this does not solve the issue, and the sheet is only presented once

Comment: If you "attach" the `.sheet` to a View outside the Scroll ? It's working just fine for me.

Comment: That’s correct, but since the sheet is originally much more nested inside the scroll view, in multiple other view structs, it seems weird to put the sheet on the top level view. That’s why I also assume this is a bug

Comment: Furthermore the fact that the presentation of the sheet works for the first time but after fails, seems not very solid to me. If it is not "allowed" in some sense it should also fail for the first time